# Reversing elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array  a and two other  int variables,  k and  temp, write a loop that reverses the elements of the array.

```
for (k = 0; k < a.length-1; k++) {
  temp = a[k];
  a[k] = a[a.length-1-k];
  a[a.length-1-k] = temp;
}
```

This is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: This would be an excellent loop to step through with a debugger.

Comment: Can you add the output to show what it is doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E.g., for `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` you'll switch `0` and `5` twice: when `i == 0` and when `i == 5`. This double-switching will put both elements into their original positions: `(0, 5) -> (5, 0) -> (0, 5)`.

Try to make your loop to go through half of array only: so each pair is switched once.

Comment: IMO when a question is tagged "homework", you shouldn't give that away too easily.

Comment: @gawi Yeah, probably it was better to omit last paragraph. But I was too hasty to post the first answer :)

Comment: I admit, it's very tempting to do so.  For "homework" questions, maybe we should up-vote answers that are more pedagogic and down-vote answers that aren't forcing the student to think or to develop an analytical skill.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop your loop at a.length/2 (in the middle).

```
for(k=0;k<a.length/2;k++)
```

This should work for odd and even length arrays if this is integer division.

Comment: Agree. Otherwise the array will be reversed twice to origin.

Answer (score 1):

check this at my blog hope this going to help http://codeheaven.wordpress.com/

**Here is the code from above link:**

```
public class ArrayReversing {
public static void main(String a[]){
int arr[]={ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8  };
int temp;
int as = arr.length;
int k = as – 1;

System.out.println(“Array Before Reversing”);
printArray(arr);//method used to print array on screen

ArrayReverse://using loops with title
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length/2 ; i++){
temp = arr[k];// swaping
arr[k] = arr[i];
arr[i] = temp;

k–;
}
System.out.println(“Array After Reversing”);
printArray(arr); // calling the method printArray to print the elements of array
}

static void printArray(int ar[]){
PrintArray:
for(int l:ar)
System.out.println(l);
}

}
```

**Output:**

```
Array Before Reversing
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Array After Reversing
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Stack. A stack reverses the elements that are added to it. A stack can be described as First In, Last Out (FILO). "Push" adds the elements to the stack and "Pop" removes them.

```
public static int[] num1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
public static Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 0; i < num1.length; i++){
        stack.push(num1[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num1.length; i++){
        System.out.print(stack.pop());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
654321
```

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping elements from each end of the array... and iterating to the items you've already swapped... is that enough of a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the [ArrayUtils.reverse](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#reverse%28int%5b%5d%29) method.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Reversearrayelementsorder.htm) is an example using that method.

I know you cannot use it in this assignment. But you should be aware of this and use it whenever possible, say in your assignments, projects.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for (int k = 0; k < a.length/2; k++) {
            int temp = a[k];
            a[k] = a[a.length-(1+k)];
            a[a.length-(1+k)] = temp;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this will simply work:**

```
public class ReverseArray{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a ={1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.